# Suppress AfterSelect event while moving a node in a TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am moving a TreeNode in a Windows Forms TreeView control as a consequence of a DragDrop event:

```
void treeViewDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    sourceNode.Remove();
    targetNode.Nodes.Add(sourceNode);
}
```

However, the Remove call triggers the AfterSelect event of the TreeView, which I need to react to if the selection really changes.

But in this case, the apparent selection change is only a result of temporarily removing the node. I don't want the selection to change at all after the node has finally moved to its target location in the tree.

So what would be the correct way to deal with that situation, i.e. how to suppress selection changes due to moving nodes?

Comment: @Dimitry's answer goes a long way imo. But :The nodes don't have an event model anyway, so it should work on the source treeview which seems to be where the selection happens..

Comment: With a bool field, `IsSelectionChangeFromDragDrop = true`, set to false after the node has been added back?

Comment: Save the selected node temporarely as a Node (or selected Index into an int). Then let treeViewDragDrop select the Node again at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not set selection programmatically, you can cancel the selection in `BeforeSelect` event if the action is not user-generated:

```
private void TreeView1_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == TreeViewAction.Unknown)
            e.Cancel=true;
    }
```

If you change selection programmatically, you may use a simple workaround by extending the TreeView class and setting a sort of "flag":

```
public class MyTreeViwe : TreeView
{
    public bool IsSuspendSelection { get; set; }

    protected override void OnBeforeSelect(TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsSuspendSelection)
            e.Cancel = true;
        else base.OnBeforeSelect(e);
    }
}
```

then do:

```
var tv = sourceNode.TreeView;
tv.IsSuspendSelection=true;
sourceNode.Remove();
tv.IsSuspendSelection=false;
```

You could also unsubscribe and then subscribe again to the `AfterSelect` event on `sourceNode.TreeView`, but I personally find this method accident-prone. There's no way to know if a given delegate is currently subscribing to a given event, and how many times. You may end up subscribing to the event multiple times and then your `AfterSelect` delegate method will run more than once.

Comment: The flag thing was indeed the first solution I had chosen. I also agree that unsubscribing events temporarily is a bit messy. But in the end I have noticed that the functionality I had inside the AfterSelect event could be better placed inside the NodeMouseClick event. So, thinking outside the box was the way to go.